# alignment of a line, if this is only minimally oblique

Tags: c#, graphics, rotation

There are two lines which do not exactly match. So sometimes they are rotated
by 1 or 2 degrees and some are slightly displaced. Now I have to write a program which detect those little mistakes and straighten them. 
The result should be that the lines are matching perfectly and that the lines are straight.
The lines are defined by a start and an ending point which are given.

A Graphiceditor is being used with a coordinate system.

Example:
first line: (320|400) (318|400)
second line: (400|320) (320|320)
The End of the two lines should be aligned perfectly together. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you please give more details? Show some minimal code, and expected and actual results with pictures maybe? Are you using winforms? WPF? UWP? Give details:)

Comment: I added some more details.

Comment: you mean you are coding a graphic editor or using a graphic editor (winforms?)? how are those lines created? Do you wish to straighten them at creation or later? What code have you tried so far?

Comment: those lines are created by giving the program two coordinates. So We read from the program and as in the example above get two lines. So we got 4 coordinates and have somehow to get the ends together which are near together. 
I really dont know how to work on that problem...

Comment: Its not winforms or anything you would know. Its a Graphic editor where I can access the lines and the object in the Graphic picture. And I also can draw lines and change them by changing coordinates.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? I assume you would want to naively parse all your couples of lines and compute some kind of angle/distance between them to determine if they should be corrected?

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. Ye, maybe with the angle between that lines and then correct it on 90 degree? But ive got no clue how to get that done...

Comment: Step 1: Understand that there will not always be a unique solution. So you will have to 2) find all solution and then 3) weigh their quality.

Comment: U are very useful... not.

Comment: @LionHunter Being offensive does not increase your chances of getting an answer. TaW actually pointed out an important detail. If you don't understand it or you are unsure what he means, then ask for clarification. For your example - can you show the desired solution and explain why you want that solution? What does alignment mean in your case?

Comment: I dont know, what there is you cant understand. So We got two lines in a coordinate system that are ALMOST together in a 90 +-3 degree angle. And I want to put that lines together,so the lines are perfectly together in a 90 degree angle.

Comment: gerrara here---

Comment: Maybe you have a typo in your example? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB894.png) is how your lines look like. I don't see a 90° angle anywhere. And what modifications do you want to allow, what do you want to preserve?

Comment: Ah I think I didnt mention that that coordinate system is not a normal one. Its positive Y-value goes for the normal coordinate system to minus Y. so positve y-values are going down from the perspective of the origin.

Comment: Doesn't really matter - the image will just be flipped. Your lines are still 80 units apart. That's why I'm asking where the 90° angle is and what you want as a result.